# Justificar texto con comando WriteHTML FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Estoy creando un texto con **fpdf**, necesito intercalar palabras en negrita, estoy utilizando una función llamada WriteHTML($html) que encontré en fpdf.org, lo que requiero es poder justificar el texto, me pueden apoyar.

```
<?php
$html = utf8_decode('<b>'.'</b>'.'Por medio de la presente se informa que al empleado'.'<b>'.' jose '.'</b>'.' con numero de empleado <b>1234</b> le es autorizado salir de vacaciones un total de <b>10 dias</b>, los cuales serán aplicados a partir del' .'día'.' <b>31/12/2019</b>');
//parte del codigo donde 
$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetLeftMargin(10);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);

$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

[image: Lo que requiero justificar]

Answer (score 2):

Con la librería FPDP tenemos la posibilidad de realizar el **justificado forzado**.

### Justificado Forzado en FPDP

##### Cell() o Multicell() nos permite justificar el texto con la **librería FPDP**

La librería FPDP puede descargarse del sitio oficial: http://fpdf.org/es/download.php

#### Tenemos dos pasos:

**Primer paso**: **crear** nuestro archivo `texto.php` para pegar el código y texto a justificar:

```
<?php
require('force_justify.php'); # necesitamos crear además este archivo

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','U',10); # tipografia
$pdf->SetFillColor(250,180,200); # RGB color de fondo

// Imprime dos celdas

$pdf->Cell(190,8,'Texto alineado izquierdo sin justificar',1,1,'L',1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(190,8,'Texto con justificado forzado',1,1,'FJ',1); # FJ es el Force Justify
$pdf->Ln();

// Imprimir con 2 Multicells

$y = $pdf->GetY();
$pdf->Multicell(90,8,"Texto alineado\nizquierdo sin justificar",1,'L',1);
$pdf->SetXY(110,$y);
$pdf->Multicell(90,8,"Texto con justificado \nforzado",1,'FJ',1); # FJ es el Force Justify
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

**Multicell**() Permite imprimir el texto en diferentes partes del documento según las coordenadas XY. Puede leerse mas al respecto en el sitio oficial.

**Segundo paso**: Ahora además de tener nuestra librería **FPDP** ya cargada en el directorio raíz y creado el archivo `texto.php` necesitamos crear el archivo `force_justify.php` .
El sitio oficial de la librería lo provee http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script8.php

Creamos el archivo `force_justify.php`

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
function Cell($w, $h=0, $txt='', $border=0, $ln=0, $align='', $fill=false, $link='')
{
    $k=$this->k;
    if($this->y+$h>$this->PageBreakTrigger && !$this->InHeader && !$this->InFooter && $this->AcceptPageBreak())
    {
        $x=$this->x;
        $ws=$this->ws;
        if($ws>0)
        {
            $this->ws=0;
            $this->_out('0 Tw');
        }
        $this->AddPage($this->CurOrientation);
        $this->x=$x;
        if($ws>0)
        {
            $this->ws=$ws;
            $this->_out(sprintf('%.3F Tw',$ws*$k));
        }
    }
    if($w==0)
        $w=$this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $s='';
    if($fill || $border==1)
    {
        if($fill)
            $op=($border==1) ? 'B' : 'f';
        else
            $op='S';
        $s=sprintf('%.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F re %s ',$this->x*$k,($this->h-$this->y)*$k,$w*$k,-$h*$k,$op);
    }
    if(is_string($border))
    {
        $x=$this->x;
        $y=$this->y;
        if(is_int(strpos($border,'L')))
            $s.=sprintf('%.2F %.2F m %.2F %.2F l S ',$x*$k,($this->h-$y)*$k,$x*$k,($this->h-($y+$h))*$k);
        if(is_int(strpos($border,'T')))
            $s.=sprintf('%.2F %.2F m %.2F %.2F l S ',$x*$k,($this->h-$y)*$k,($x+$w)*$k,($this->h-$y)*$k);
        if(is_int(strpos($border,'R')))
            $s.=sprintf('%.2F %.2F m %.2F %.2F l S ',($x+$w)*$k,($this->h-$y)*$k,($x+$w)*$k,($this->h-($y+$h))*$k);
        if(is_int(strpos($border,'B')))
            $s.=sprintf('%.2F %.2F m %.2F %.2F l S ',$x*$k,($this->h-($y+$h))*$k,($x+$w)*$k,($this->h-($y+$h))*$k);
    }
    if($txt!='')
    {
        if($align=='R')
            $dx=$w-$this->cMargin-$this->GetStringWidth($txt);
        elseif($align=='C')
            $dx=($w-$this->GetStringWidth($txt))/2;
        elseif($align=='FJ')
        {
            //Set word spacing
            $wmax=($w-2*$this->cMargin);
            $this->ws=($wmax-$this->GetStringWidth($txt))/substr_count($txt,' ');
            $this->_out(sprintf('%.3F Tw',$this->ws*$this->k));
            $dx=$this->cMargin;
        }
        else
            $dx=$this->cMargin;
        $txt=str_replace(')','\\)',str_replace('(','\\(',str_replace('\\','\\\\',$txt)));
        if($this->ColorFlag)
            $s.='q '.$this->TextColor.' ';
        $s.=sprintf('BT %.2F %.2F Td (%s) Tj ET',($this->x+$dx)*$k,($this->h-($this->y+.5*$h+.3*$this->FontSize))*$k,$txt);
        if($this->underline)
            $s.=' '.$this->_dounderline($this->x+$dx,$this->y+.5*$h+.3*$this->FontSize,$txt);
        if($this->ColorFlag)
            $s.=' Q';
        if($link)
        {
            if($align=='FJ')
                $wlink=$wmax;
            else
                $wlink=$this->GetStringWidth($txt);
            $this->Link($this->x+$dx,$this->y+.5*$h-.5*$this->FontSize,$wlink,$this->FontSize,$link);
        }
    }
    if($s)
        $this->_out($s);
    if($align=='FJ')
    {
        //Remove word spacing
        $this->_out('0 Tw');
        $this->ws=0;
    }
    $this->lasth=$h;
    if($ln>0)
    {
        $this->y+=$h;
        if($ln==1)
            $this->x=$this->lMargin;
    }
    else
        $this->x+=$w;
}
}
?>
```

El resultado será un PDF ubicado en `texto.php` con la siguiente presentación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf->WriteHTML("<div style='text-align: justify;'".$html."</div>")
```

Lo correcto sería que viniera ya alineado en ese $html.