# Generar ciertas palabras en negritas dentro de la funcion Multicell usando FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Hola gente como se habia mencionado en la pregunta, quiero escribir un texto grande pero con algunas palabras en negritas resaltando su inportancia dentro del parrafo pero como menciono, el texto es muy amplio entonces se me hizo una excelente idea usar multicell para guardar todo el texto y que se justifique solo, pero ahora que quiero agregar letras en negritas a algunas palabras ya no me deja jaja, creen que puedan ayudarme

Les muestro mi código

```
if (isset($_GET["id_usuario"])) {

    require_once 'fpdf.php';
    require_once 'MetodosUsuarios.php';
    $id_empleado = $_GET["id_usuario"];
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');
    //Objeto FPDF
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    class pdf extends FPDF{
        function Header()
    {   
        switch ($_GET) {
        case isset($_GET['id_usuario']):    
              $this->Image('../img/Cabecera.png', 10, 10, 90, 17);
              $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
    
        break;
        }
    
      
    
    }
    
    function Footer()
    {   
    
      switch ($_GET) {

        
      case isset($_GET['id_usuario']):
          include_once 'MetodosUsuarios.php';
          $usuario_1 = new MetodosUsuarios();
          $id_empleado = $_GET["id_usuario"];
          $objUsuario = $usuario_1->Para_responsiva($id_empleado);
          $admin = $objUsuario["id_admin"];
          $Aut = $usuario_1->Para_responsiva1($id_empleado,$admin);
    
          $domicilio = $Aut["direccion"];
          $this->SetDrawColor(188,149,0);
          $this->SetLineWidth(3);
          $this->Line(168, 282, 20, 282);
          $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 7);
          $this->SetTextColor(188,149,0);
        
         
          $this->Image('../img/pie_pag,png.png', 168, 278, 30, 16);
          $this->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
          $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 7);
          $this->Text(195, 290, utf8_decode( 'Pag. '. $this->PageNo()));
    
      break;
      }
    
    }
    
    }    

$pdf = new pdf();
        //Creamos un documento
        $pdf->AddPage();
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
        $pdf->SetTitle("$sistema | Carta responsiva");
    
    
    
    
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
        $pdf->Text(65, 48, utf8_decode("Carta Responsiva ". $sistema.""));
    
     
        
        $pdf->Ln();
        $pdf->SetXY(25,55);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
        $pdf->MultiCell(160,3,utf8_decode("El que suscribe ".$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10).$nombre.$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10)."en mi calidad Empleado de la fabrica Famsa, con número de empleado $no_empleado y Registro   Federal de  Contribuyentes $rfc adscrito a la sede 4 y correo electrónico $correo, manifiesto que con la suscripción   de la  presente responsiva, asumo la responsabilidad del acceso y del  debido  uso  de  la  información en el."),0,'J',0);
    $pdf->Close();
        $pdf->Output();
}
```

Bueno por el momento asi seria todo lo que puedo mostrar

Comment: En la página de FPDF, exactamente en el [Tutorial #6](http://www.fpdf.org/es/tutorial/tuto6.htm), muestra una función con HTML donde puedes realizar todas esas modificaciones que deseas.

Comment: si, ya lo he intentado con html pero el texto pierde su forma y no se justifica como con la instruccion en multicell incluso el tamaño de letra no se puede ajustar

Comment: ya lo he intentado con esa funcion de hecho se que de descarga por separado y se agrega al archivo pero aun tiene sus detalles

Comment: Hola, fijate si te sirve esta respuesta de texto justificado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317478/justificar-texto-con-comando-writehtml/506103#506103